# Getting a variable from a thread to be used by a function

Tags: java

This may be a really simple question, but things I've tried don't seem to work. I admit my understanding of Java is not that great and this is the first time I've worked with `Threads`, so here it goes,

```
public MockDataGenerator() {

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    if (bayeuxIds.size() > 0) {

                        System.out.println("These are the bayeuxIds from new Thread" + bayeuxIds);
                        List<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();
                        users.addAll(bayeuxIds);
                        setData(users);
                        Collections.shuffle(users);
                        String bayeuxId = users.get(0);
                        List<Alert> alerts = generateRandomAlerts(1);
                        alertsAdded(bayeuxId, alerts);

                    }
                } catch (Throwable t) {

                } finally {
                    try {
                        int numUsers = bayeuxIds.size();

                        // plus 1 prevents divide by zero
                        sleep(30000);
                        //sleep(r.nextInt(120000 / (numUsers + 1)));

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();

}

public void onMessage(Message message) {
    System.out.println("Message recieved from ActiveMQ");


    if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
        try {

            System.out.println("This is the 0th element of usersCopy: " + users.get(0));
            String bayeuxId = users.get(0);


            String theMsg = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
            clientMessanger.sendUpdate(theMsg, bayeuxId);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Message must be of type TextMessage");
    }

}
```

**Edit 1:**

Edited to show the full code, basically what I want is the users List from the Thread to be passed into the onMessage function. I tried some getters and setters but that did not work since I assume I have to use a syncronized function in order for that to work right?

**Edit 2:**

Added these functions but it still doesn't seem to be setting the variables right. What am I doing wrong?

```
    String bayeuxIdCopy;

public synchronized void setData(String bayeuxId) {
    System.out.println("This is the bayeuxID being set:  " + bayeuxId);
    bayeuxIdCopy = bayeuxId;
}

public synchronized String getData() {
    System.out.println("This is the bayeuxID being returned:  " + bayeuxIdCopy);
    return bayeuxIdCopy;
}
```

Comment: There's a bunch of stuff missing, without which it's hard to understand the question.  Why is `generateRandom()` wrapped in a thread? When you run the thread it will execute once and quit... or does it infinite-loop internally, in which case how do you tell it when you've retrieved a value?  Where is the code that starts the thread?  How does the second code block relate to the first? There doesn't seem to be any connection.

Comment: @JimGarrison Added full code now, hopefully it makes sense now. I'll clarify the best I can if it is not.

Comment: Use a class level variable which is visible to both thread (since its an inner class and your onMessage method). You may use synchronized collection class so that the list is not edited by multiple threads at any given time.

Comment: You should try adding a handler to your thread.

Comment: What is the expected and actual behavior?  I can't tell what "doesn't seem to be setting the variables right" means.   What is the right way it should be set?  When is onMessage() being called.  Does bayeuxIds change independently of the thread (in which case it needs to be synchronized).

Comment: Solved, just had to set bayeuxId as static. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to extend the Thread class and create a constructor that takes an object that you instantiate before hand and pass the object in to the constructor. This will allow the Thread to alter the object and be able to see the changes outside the thread. This is the cleanest way.

Also you can create an object inside the `MockDataGenerator` and outside the `new Thread` statement. This will also be accessible outside the thread with the changes.

Comment: Edit, see modified original post, still for the life of me cannot figure out SO's comment system markup.

Comment: Need more details of what you've put in your code. If both the variable and functions are within the thread, you won't be able to access the variable outside of the thread.